# Kubernetes coredns readiness probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster with one master (kube-master) and 2 slaves (kube-node-01 and kube-node-02)

All was running fine ... now after debian stretch -> buster upgrade my coredns pods are failing with `CrashLoopBackOff` for some reason.

I did a `kubectl describe` and the error is `Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503`

The Readiness url looks suspicious to me `http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3` ... there is no hostname !? is that correct?

The `Liveness` property also does not have a hostname.

All vm's are pingable from each other.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I met similar issue when upgrade my host machine to ubuntu 18.04 which uses systemd-resolved as DNS server. The nameserver field in /etc/resolv.conf is using a local IP address 127.0.0.53 which would cause coreDNS failed to start.

You can take a look at the details from the following link.
https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/loop/README.md#troubleshooting-loops-in-kubernetes-clusters

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this problem myself. Apparently the lack of a hostname in the healthcheck url is ok.

What got me ahead was

```
microk8s.inspect
```

The output said there's a problem with forwarding on iptables. Since I have firewalld on my system, I temporarily disabled it

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

and then disabled dns in microk8s and enabled it again (for some unknown reason the dns pod didn't get up on it's own)

```
microk8s.disable dns
microk8s.enable dns
```

it started without any issues.

Comment: Nice answer for a first try. Could you please put a bit more effort in it. Some reformating and some specific informations about your sources and solution we be nice too.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware anyone pays much attention to how an answer is presented. I'm used to replying on IRC and other text chats without formatting.

Comment: A lot of us is doing reviewing posts, especially when the author is a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would start troubleshooting with [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) agent verification on the master and worker nodes in order exclude any intercommunication issue within a cluster nodes whenever the rest core runtime Pods are up and running, as `kubelet` is the main contributor for 
[Liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) and [Readiness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) probes.

```
systemctl status kubelet -l

journalctl -u kubelet
```

Mentioned in the question health check URLs are fine, as they are predefined in [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) deployment per design.

Ensure that [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) plugin Pods are functioning and cluster overlay network intercepts requests from Pod to Pod communication as CoreDNS is very sensitive on any issue related to entire cluster networking.

In addition to @Hang Du answer about CoreDNS pods loopback issue, I encourage you to get more information regarding CoreDNS problems investigation in official k8s debug [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state).